# layout_marginTop in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, layoutmargins

I am trying to create a login page for an app in Android Studio. The XML code for the page is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".LoginChoice">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/userbtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:onClick="userloginIntent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/user_login_button_small"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/white" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/driverbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:onClick="driverloginIntent"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:text="@string/driver_login"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg1"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userbtn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem here is that the `Button`s that I am using, appear much lower on running the app in my phone than they do in the `Design` area in Android Studio.
Here's how it looks in android studio-
[image]

And here is a screenshot of when I run the app on my phone-
[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You set top margin to your userBtn = 450dp. This value will be different based on device's screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, you can choose the device that you are using to visualize your `layout.xml`, the default device may not be have the dimensions as your physical device. You can change it or add a device definition to match your desired device. Also, you could use [Layout Validation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to see a more accurate preview of your design.

Remember that you are using `dp` as a unit measure, not standard `pixels`.

[image]