# Android app looks different in the Android studio emulator than on my phone, how can this be fixed?

Tags: android

When the app is run in the Android Studio emulator (emulating a Pixel phone), it looks fine, but when it is run on my phone (a Samsung A20e), it doesn't display the same way. I am aware that the Samsung A20e has a different aspect ratio to the Pixel, which is causing the app to display improperly, but I don't know how to fix it. [This is a screenshot from the Pixel emulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTS1R.png) [This is a screenshot from my A20e, running the same app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz76R.jpg) As you can see, the UI is compressed when the app runs on my phone.

This is the XML used in the layout (the same XML is running on both my phone and the emulator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/amount_to_borrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/amountBorrowedTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/amountBorrowedEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/amountBorrowedTextView"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/termTextView"
            android:text="@string/term_in_years"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amountBorrowedTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/termEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/termTextView"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/interestRateTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/termTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/interest_rate"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/interestRateEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/interestRateTextView"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/percentageSignTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/interestRateEditText"
            android:text="@string/percentage_sign"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/interestOnlySwitch"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/interest_only" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/singlePeriodOnlySwitch"
            android:text="@string/single_period_only"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/monthly_payment"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/monthlyPaymentCaptionTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/interestRateTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.50" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/monthlyPaymentEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/monthlyPaymentCaptionTextView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I need to know is how to create a layout that works on different screen aspect ratios, or to at least simplify making such a layout. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66566665/15298643), but also, you could create a different layout per dimensions or orientation

Comment: hi try to  set a fixed height  on you calculate Button don't use 0dp

Comment: What's the problem? You can't have the layout look the same on all devices when the devices are fundamentally different with i.e. different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will always be a problem when you use fixed dimensions. So unless you are confident that there won't be any overlap, fixed values should be avoided.

For example, your `amountBorrowedEditText` has a fixed `ems` of 10, whereas it probably should be constrained between the label and the end of the parent, with a width of `0dp`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be constraining your items based on each other. For example the first textview and edittext would look like this

```
<TextView
            android:text="@string/amount_to_borrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/amountBorrowedTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/amountBorrowedEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/amountBorrowedTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/amountBorrowedTextView"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
```

This would make sure the edit text is always to the right of the textview and fill the rest of the remaining space